# Field code IF statement not working

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, microsoft-word-2010, field-codes

I have a simple IF statement which should be checking whether a `docvariable` is set to `YES` or `NO`. Regardless of whether it's Y/N, the document is including the `"Some text here"` part and the second `docvariable`. It never seems to get to the true condition.

These are VB docvariables and I have checked the value by displaying them in the document. It's always set to either `YES` or `NO`. I've even tried `1` and `0` just incase. No luck.

Can anyone see an error in my syntax or think of anything else that could be causing this problem? Picture below. If anyone cannot see it, I'm happy to type it out.

[image: Document IF statement]

Comment: @Yorik that did the trick! Thanks :) Feel free to post it as the answer and I'll mark it as so as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but usually text comparisons are case sensitive, so force the comparison to upper or lower. Cannot remember, but you might add `\*Upper`inside the docvariable brackets as the last parameter(??) e.g. `AITEM1RATEYN" \*Upper}`. Again, memory hazy

Comment: This is correct in terms of syntax - `\*UPPER` appended to the field code